# Forecast an OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm doing much image processing in my WPF application. Can I gather informations about the RAM space that is allocated to my application by the .NET Framework? I would use it to prevent an OutOfMemory Exception.

In fact, I get an OutOfMemory Exception with 2.3GB RAM usage, eventhough the system has enough capabilities for providing more than 3 GB.

**EDIT:**
Here are some more information about the context, in which the exception is happening:

- 32-Bit application. I know that I cannot use more than 4 GB RAM. But why can't I use at least 3 GB if available? As it is no 64-Bit application, `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>` is currently no option for me.
- The application is running on a 64-Bit Windows 8.1. The computer has 8 GB RAM available. When the exception happens, 86% of RAM are used.
- If I run the application on a Windows 10 64-Bit OS, I can use full 4 GB RAM as expected. This computer has 16GB of RAM available and is my development device.
- Profiling & Analysing is in my case difficult, as the exception does not happen on my PC but on an users device. All informations about the hardware of that system are given in the second point of this list. Based on the users feedback, I cannot specify a specific code snippet in which the exception is thrown.

Is it possible that the use of further RAM capabilities is restricted by windows on the users device? Or is an issue with the GC more likely?

Comment: Please show us your existing code in which OOM is being thrown. It is likely you aren't calling `Dispose` where you should. Additionally, have you set https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element to true?

Comment: Tried using the Profiler & analyzing memory usage?

Comment: Is it a 32 bit or 64 bit application? And what about the OS? If it is 32 bits, are you using the option to get 3GB (not sure if applicable to .NET application). How much RAM does the computer has? It is already a lot of memory fo0r a single application. If you use almost all memory then the system can become very slow if is to use the swap file too much. There are tools to analyse memory usage. And by the way, they are many way to count memory (per application or global, reserved or committed, physical or virtual...) so 2 numbers out of the context are not that much meaningful.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I added some more informations to the question.

Comment: Probably there's a LOH fragmentation that causes the `OutOfMemoryExcepton`. I would suggest you to investigate this.